# Solving $\frac{1 - \cos(y/2)}{\pi d} \cdot 180c=y$ for $y$

Tags: trigonometry, problem-solving

I have been trying to solve a problem that came to me randomly about a week ago, and I am very close to solving it but have reached a roadblock when re-arranging the final equation to solve it. I do not believe the problem is necessary, but here is the equation (and the cosine function is using degrees not radians)

$$\frac {1-\cos\left(\dfrac {y}{2}\right)} {(\pi d)} \cdot 180c = y$$
$c$ and $d$ are just variables that I can substitute in based off of the situation.

I need to re arrange to solve for $y$. However, I seem to be unable to get the $y$ inside the cosine out without putting the other $y$ inside an arccosine.

Is there any way to solve this or is it impossible?

After plotting it on Desmos with sample data, I found three solutions: $0$, the expected solution, and some other irrational number like $496$ which is fine as the expected solution was an integer so easy to spot. So with sample data, there are $3$ solutions to this and one of them is $0$. I don't know whether this will help but I have included it just in case it does.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry for the mistaken edit. It is supposed to be multiplied by $180c$. Will fix it as soon as I can.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math SE. Given the $180/\pi$ factor, is $y$ measured in degrees? You'd probably make more progress if you worked in radians instead.

Comment: Yes $y$ is measured in degrees and c and d are measurements of length

Comment: I have tried to use radians however that just gave me more solutions when plotting the graph? I am very unexperienced with radians and in my current situation it simply seems much more logical to use degrees?

Comment: Hi Jim - I formatted your equation, but if you want to try it yourself in the future, this is a good reference...https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Thanks bjcolby15. I will try learn that for future questions!

Comment: Your equation can be turned into a [Kepler equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=kepler+equation)